# Using AsyncTask to download an XML file

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httprequest

I've been working on a simple weather app - and I'm using the Google Weather API. I'm trying to download the XML file and build the UI based on the info in it.

I try using AsyncTask to download the XML file and then parse it - but something's not working! When I run the code I don't have any error / the app starts but the info from the xml file is not shown!

Here's the code:

```
    package com.android.weatherApp;



public class WeatherAppActivity extends Activity {

    static String url="http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=";
    static final String KEY_FORCAST_INFO="forcast_information";
    static final String KEY_CITY="city";
    static final String KEY_CURRENT_CONDITIONS="current_conditions";
    static final String KEY_CONDITION="condition";
    static final String KEY_TEMP="temp_c";
    static final String KEY_ICON_SRC="icon";
    static final String KEY_FORCAST_COND="forecast_conditions";
    static final String KEY_DAY_WEEK="day_of_week";
    static final String KEY_LOW_TEMP="low";
    static final String KEY_HIGH_TEMP="high";
    Document finalDoc;
    XMLParser xmlParser;
    private TextView currentWeather;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        downloadXMLFile task=new downloadXMLFile();
        task.execute("New+York");

    }

    private class downloadXMLFile extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String xml=null;

            try{
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost(url+params[0]);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity=httpResponse.getEntity();
                xml=EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            }
            catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return xml;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String xmlString)
        {
            Document doc = null;
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

            try {
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                InputSource is=new InputSource();

                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlString));
                doc=db.parse(is);

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finalDoc=doc;

            NodeList nl=finalDoc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_CURRENT_CONDITIONS);
              NodeList nl2=finalDoc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_FORCAST_COND);
              currentWeather=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.currentState);
              TextView currentTemp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tempC);
              TextView currentLocation=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.currentLocation);
              currentLocation.setText("Iasi");

              for(int i=0;i<nl.getLength();i++)
              {
                Element e= (Element)nl.item(i);
                String cs=xmlParser.getValue(e, KEY_CONDITION).toUpperCase();
                currentWeather.setText(cs);

                String temperature=xmlParser.getValue(e, KEY_TEMP);
                currentTemp.setText(temperature);

                String logoImg=xmlParser.getValue(e, KEY_ICON_SRC).toLowerCase();

                if(logoImg.equals("/ig/images/weather/sunny.gif"))
                {
                    ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.wImg);
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.sun);
                }

              }

              for(int i=0;i<nl2.getLength();i++)
              {
                Element e=(Element)nl2.item(i);
                TextView day1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.day1);
                day1.setText("TOMORW");
                TextView day2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.day2);
                TextView day3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.day3);
                ImageView img1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.day1Logo);
                ImageView img2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.day2Logo);
                ImageView img3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.day3Logo);
                TextView highTemp1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.day1MaxTemp);
                TextView highTemp2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.day2MaxTemp);
                TextView highTemp3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.day3MaxTemp);

                String d1=xmlParser.getValue(e, KEY_DAY_WEEK).toUpperCase();
                String t=xmlParser.getValue(e, KEY_HIGH_TEMP); //get the max value of temperature - Fahrenheit
                int tempF=Integer.parseInt(t); // make the string a number
                float tC=(float) ((5./9)*(tempF-32)); // calculate the Celsius value of temperature
                tempF=(int)tC; // get only the Int value
                t=Integer.toString(tempF); // transform the temperature value back to string

                switch(i)
                {
                case 1:
                    highTemp1.setText(t);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    highTemp2.setText(t);
                    day2.setText(d1);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    highTemp3.setText(t);
                    day3.setText(d1);
                    break;
                }
              }
        }

    }
```

Please if you can tell me what am I doing wrong. 
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to debug your app?

Comment: Can you post your logcat? Also, I would recommend parsing in DoInBackground not in PostExecute ... just a personal preference though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your url variable contains "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=" not "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=New+York" so the xml content is empty.

Try something like this in doInBackground method :

```
String currentUrl = url; 
if(params.length>0 && params[0]!=null)currentUrl+= params[0];
```

I see that you instanciate your Views inside a loop. You must instanciate them inside your onCreate method or onStart method. Doing this, you will instanciate these variables after your activity is created and you will gain performance.

Comment: When I call "task.execute("New+York") - the httpPost=new HttpPost(url+"New York") // the string from execute - so the xml file is not empty!

Comment: Are your sure ? Because from your code, I see `HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost(url);`, so you never call you param value.

Comment: Yes - I changed it httpPost=new HttpPost(url+params); - so i guess the url should be ok!

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, have you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` ?

Can you put `Log.i("test",xmlString);` in your onPostExecute and see in your log the result ?

Comment: Yes - I have the permission in the manifest! The xmlString is the same with the xml string from the doOnBackground() method! It's the the content from the xml file I'm trying to use!

Comment: Can you try to put in onStart method the instanciation of your views ?